# Determine whether this set of vectors is linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

[image]

I changed it to row echelon form and found that the rank is 4

As 4 is not less than the number of vectors (4), it is linearly independent

Is something wrong? The answer says that it is linearly dependent

Comment: Yeah if the rank is 4, they should be linearly independent. Row echelon form is super easy to make mistakes so make sure you've done the calculations correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(0,-4,1,1)=(1,0,2,-3)+(1,-2,-1,3)-(2,2,0,-1)$$
You seem to have made a calculation error.